# How to receive broadcast event even when my App is in background in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, background-process

I  have a  app  which is  a single  activity app ,  it  listens  to many broadcast  event  , my  question is  that  how  can I  ensure that I receive  all the  fired  intent  which i  have   added  for my app  even  when  my  app  is not  in  foreground and  running in  background ??

> is  there a  certain  method   where 
>   I  should add my intent  filter and 
>   do the  registerReciever ?  I'm   sure 
>   it  won't  work  if  I keep  it in
>   "Oncreate"

any ideas  or help ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be using a BroadcastReceiver to pick up the events when you are in the 'background'. This will pick up events which are actually broadcast without having to launch a UI.

You can set up the BroadcastReceiver and its intent filters in the manifest for your application, this way you dont have to rely on any java code being run to register the receivers.

Comment: hmm sounds  right   how  do i  right my  "BroadcastReceiver "  in manifest i  know  about  intent  filter  but not  about "BroadcastReceiver " can be  written in  manifest  as well...                    what if i need to  to have  2  different BroadcastReceiver    based on  different intent  filter  can  this  be done  thru  manifest  as well ??

Comment: Yes, you can define multiple broadcast receivers, or multiple intent filters for a single receiver. Look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html

Comment: yes  that did  help  ..but    my  doubts  still  stays   what if i  have to make  two different  bropadcastrecievers...  in a  single class ?  CAn this be  done ??  if yes  then   how  do  we  distinguish among the two  as in  "android:name" field in  manifest only the  class name is mentioned but not the  child class of  BroadcastReceiver..can this be  done  ??

Comment: In that case would just create a single revceiver but add 2 intent filters for the different intents you want it to process. so you would have a single receiver node in you manifset that has the name of the subclass of BroadcastReceiver you are using, and multiple intent-filter nodes